# Best practise applying fix to tagged code in Git

Tags: git, github

I need to fix some code stored in GitHub and I'm not sure how to proceed while keeping all my branches/tags/revisions clean and sensible.

I have a number of branches including `devel` and `master` as well as a number of tags (`v1`, `v2`, etc.).  After completing a chunk of code on `devel` I merged it into `master` and created a tag `v11`.  I used that tag to deploy on a test server.

In the meantime I carried on with additional development on `devel` so that it is now ahead of `master`.

I found a small unexpected bug in the tagged version, and I have a simple (2-line) fix for it.  What is the Git-approved way to deal with this?

Should I checkout `master` at the revision corresponding to the tag `v11`, then make the fix, then push to `master`, then retag (i.e.: delete the old tag and add a new tag with the same name - I don't mind doing this because nobody is using this tag yet)?  Then make the same change to my local `devel` branch so that it doesn't get undone the next time I merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fix the bug in `master` and create a new tag `v11.1`.

I would then re-base `devel` on top of `master`.

Comment: I didn't know about rebase.  That sounds like the right approach.  Thanks.

Comment: I like that it leaves nice clean trees. Others prefer (messier) `merge`s, which can be useful tracking changes between members of a team for example